# Get resultset from oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm working on converting a stored procedure from SQL server  to Oracle. 
This stored procedure provides a direct resultset. I mean that if you call the stored procedure in eg Management Studio you directly obtain the resultset.

By converting to Oracle I walk against the problem that I in Oracle will not display the resultset

I searched on the Internet and have seen that the stored procedure should yield a REF CURSOR, but I still walk with the problem to write a little piece of code to obtain the resultset en process that.

Pseudo Code:

Call stored procedure and obtain cursor
Do something with that cursor so that my resultset appears

Someone an idea?

Comment: I wounder. This question has > 90K views and has got only 20 up-vote. It deserves up-vote per view. :D

Comment: @Dr.MAF The question has almost 110,000 views now. Pretty astonishing if you ask me.

Comment: @Wilson Sorry, I didn't get your idea. What shall I ask you?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In SQL Plus:

```
SQL> create procedure myproc (prc out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4     open prc for select * from emp;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> execute myproc(:rc)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE           SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-1981       4999                    10
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-1981       2849                    30
      7782 CLARKE     MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-1981       2449                    10
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-1981       2974                    20
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09-DEC-1982       2999                    20
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-1981       2999                    20
      7369 SMITHY     CLERK           7902 17-DEC-1980       9988         11         20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-1981       1599       3009         30
      7521 WARDS      SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-1981       1249        551         30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-1981       1249       1400         30
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-1981       1499          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12-JAN-1983       1099                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-1981        949                    30
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-1982       1299                    10
      6668 Umberto    CLERK           7566 11-JUN-2009      19999          0         10
      9567 ALLBRIGHT  ANALYST         7788 02-JUN-2009      76999         24         10
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the Answer, Tony. Can I export these results to CSV through Unix/Linux script?

Comment: print rc is nice in sql plus, how can I have rc displayed in a grid in SQL Developer?

Comment: I wounder. This question has > 90K views and has got only 20 up-vote. It deserves up-vote per view. And your answer deserves 10 up-votes per view. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would like to ask the same question asked by @Stack0verflow above. How to show this result in grid format ?

Comment: @MuhammadAsim As far as I know, you can't.  PRINT command is supported in SQL Developer but writes the output in text format to Script Output tab.

Comment: @TonyAndrews thank you for clarification but is there any way to do so ?

Comment: My savior! I have been stuck for 6 hours on a similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to create a pipelined function.   The advantages are that the query can be a single line:

- `select * from table(yourfunction(param1, param2));`
- You can join your results to other tables or filter or sort them as you please..
- the results appear as regular query results so you can easily manipulate them.

To define the function you would need to do something like the following:

```
  -- Declare the record columns
  TYPE your_record IS RECORD(
     my_col1 VARCHAR2(50), 
     my_col2 varchar2(4000)
  );
  TYPE your_results IS TABLE OF your_record;

  -- Declare the function
  function yourfunction(a_Param1 varchar2, a_Param2 varchar2)
  return your_results pipelined is
    rt          your_results;
  begin
    -- Your query to load the table type
    select s.col1,s.col2
    bulk collect into rt
    from your_table s
    where lower(s.col1) like lower('%'||a_Param1||'%');

    -- Stuff the results into the pipeline..
    if rt.count > 0 then 
      for i in rt.FIRST .. rt.LAST loop 
        pipe row (rt(i)); 
      end loop; 
    end if;

    -- Add more results as you please....
    return;
  end find;
```

And as mentioned above, all you would do to view your results is:

```
select * from table(yourfunction(param1, param2)) t order by t.my_col1;
```

Comment: The benefit of this solution over the accepted solution is that the results are returned just like any regular select statement meaning your calling code doesn't need to do anything different when populating some kind of data structure like a table or array (which is what you need to do 99% of the time so you can do further processing in the calling code). With the accepted solution the results are printed so the calling code needs to parse the printed result to get the data into some kind of data structure which can be very error prone.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle is not sql server. Try the following in SQL Developer

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec testproc(:rc2);
print rc2
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I know this was asked a while ago but I've just figured this out and it might help someone else. Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but this is how I call a stored proc and view the output using SQL Developer.
In SQL Developer when viewing the proc, right click and choose 'Run' or select Ctrl+F11 to bring up the Run PL/SQL window. This creates a template with the input and output params which you need to modify. My proc returns a sys_refcursor. The tricky part for me was declaring a row type that is exactly equivalent to the select stmt / sys_refcursor being returned by the proc:

```
DECLARE
  P_CAE_SEC_ID_N NUMBER;
  P_FM_SEC_CODE_C VARCHAR2(200);
  P_PAGE_INDEX NUMBER;
  P_PAGE_SIZE NUMBER;
  v_Return sys_refcursor;
  type t_row is record (CAE_SEC_ID NUMBER,FM_SEC_CODE VARCHAR2(7),rownum number, v_total_count number);
  v_rec t_row;

BEGIN
  P_CAE_SEC_ID_N := NULL;
  P_FM_SEC_CODE_C := NULL;
  P_PAGE_INDEX := 0;
  P_PAGE_SIZE := 25;

  CAE_FOF_SECURITY_PKG.GET_LIST_FOF_SECURITY(
    P_CAE_SEC_ID_N => P_CAE_SEC_ID_N,
    P_FM_SEC_CODE_C => P_FM_SEC_CODE_C,
    P_PAGE_INDEX => P_PAGE_INDEX,
    P_PAGE_SIZE => P_PAGE_SIZE,
    P_FOF_SEC_REFCUR => v_Return
  );
  -- Modify the code to output the variable
  -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('P_FOF_SEC_REFCUR = ');
  loop
    fetch v_Return into v_rec;
    exit when v_Return%notfound;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sec_id = ' || v_rec.CAE_SEC_ID || 'sec code = ' ||v_rec.FM_SEC_CODE);
  end loop;

END;
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI as of Oracle 12c, you can do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc(n number)
AS
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR SELECT object_id,object_name from all_objects where rownum < n;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur);
END;
/

EXEC testproc(3);

OBJECT_ID OBJECT_NAME                                                                                                                     
---------- ------------
100 ORA$BASE                                                                                                                        
116 DUAL
```

This was supposed to get closer to other databases, and ease migrations.
But it's not perfect to me, for instance SQL developer won't display it nicely as a normal SELECT.

I prefer the output of pipeline functions, but they need more boilerplate to code.

more info:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1

Comment: @Ejrr1085 did you use 'run script' (F5). works for me. I didn't have to do the usual  'set serveroutput on', but you may try this as well.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Plus:

```
SQL> var r refcursor
SQL> set autoprint on
SQL> exec :r := function_returning_refcursor();
```

Replace the last line with a call to your procedure / function and the contents of the refcursor will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_Invoices(p_nameClient IN CHAR)
AS
BEGIN       
    FOR c_invoice IN 
    (
       SELECT CodeInvoice, NameClient FROM Invoice
       WHERE NameClient = p_nameClient
    )
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Code Invoice: ' || c_invoice.CodeInvoice);
        dbms_output.put_line('Name Client : ' ||  c_invoice.NameClient );
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Executing in SQL Developer:

```
BEGIN
    SP_Invoices('Perico de los palotes');
END;
-- Or:
EXEC SP_Invoices('Perico de los palotes');
```

Output:

```
> Code Invoice: 1 
> Name Client : Perico de los palotes
> Code Invoice: 2 
> Name Client : Perico de los palotes
```