# Declaring & Setting Variables in a Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql

I'm attempting to write a simple query where I declare some variables and then use them in a select statement in Oracle.  I've been able to do this before in SQL Server with the following:

```
DECLARE @date1   DATETIME
SET @date1 = '03-AUG-2010'

SELECT U.VisualID
FROM Usage u WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE U.UseTime > @Date1
```

From the searching I've done it appears you can not declare and set variables like this in Select statements.  Is this right or am I mssing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*From the searching I've done it appears you can not declare and set variables like this in Select statements. Is this right or am I missing something?*

Within Oracle PL/SQL and SQL are two separate languages with two separate engines. You can embed SQL DML within PL/SQL, and that will get you variables. Such as the following anonymous PL/SQL block. Note the `/` at the end is not part of PL/SQL, but tells SQL*Plus to send the preceding block.

```
declare 
    v_Date1 date := to_date('03-AUG-2010', 'DD-Mon-YYYY');
    v_Count number;
begin
    select count(*) into v_Count
    from Usage
    where UseTime > v_Date1;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_Count);
end;
/
```

The problem is that a block that is equivalent to your T-SQL code will not work:

```
SQL> declare 
  2      v_Date1 date := to_date('03-AUG-2010', 'DD-Mon-YYYY');
  3  begin
  4      select VisualId
  5      from Usage
  6      where UseTime > v_Date1;
  7  end;
  8  /
    select VisualId
    *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

To pass the results of a query out of an PL/SQL, either an anonymous block, stored procedure or stored function, a cursor must be declared, opened and then returned to the calling program. (Beyond the scope of answering this question. **EDIT:** see [Get resultset from oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170548/get-resultset-from-oracle-stored-procedure))

The client tool that connects to the database may have it's own bind variables. In SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> -- SQL*Plus does not all date type in this context
SQL> -- So using varchar2 to hold text
SQL> variable v_Date1 varchar2(20)
SQL>
SQL> -- use PL/SQL to set the value of the bind variable
SQL> exec :v_Date1 := '02-Aug-2010';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> -- Converting to a date, since the variable is not yet a date.
SQL> -- Note the use of colon, this tells SQL*Plus that v_Date1
SQL> -- is a bind variable.
SQL> select VisualId
  2  from Usage
  3  where UseTime > to_char(:v_Date1, 'DD-Mon-YYYY');

no rows selected
```

Note the above is in SQL*Plus, may not (probably won't) work in Toad PL/SQL developer, etc. The lines starting with variable and exec are SQL*Plus commands. They are not SQL or PL/SQL commands. No rows selected because the table is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this and it worked:

```
define PROPp_START_DT = TO_DATE('01-SEP-1999')

select * from proposal where prop_start_dt = &PROPp_START_DT
```

Answer (score 2):

The `SET` command is TSQL specific - here's the PLSQL equivalent to what you posted:

```
v_date1 DATE := TO_DATE('03-AUG-2010', 'DD-MON-YYYY');

SELECT u.visualid
  FROM USAGE u 
 WHERE u.usetime > v_date1;
```

There's also no need for prefixing variables with "@"; I tend to prefix variables with "v_" to distinguish between variables & columns/etc.

See [this thread about the Oracle equivalent of NOLOCK](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=654190)...

Answer (score 0):

Try the [to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to set a date value (or a VARCHAR2 value) and then reference it in the select statement.  I thought the TO_DATE was more of a function to convert a string into an Oracle date.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from SQL Server as well, and this really bugged me. For those using *Toad Data Point* or *Toad for Oracle*, it's extremely simple. Just putting a colon in front of your variable name will prompt Toad to open a dialog where you enter the value on execute.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = :var_name;
```