# doing a oracle stored procedure for a query that have subquerys

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-mvc, stored-procedures

hi is it posible to create a stored procedure that have a subquery and a union statement

i have a query like this that i want to convert it in a stored procedure so i can get the values that return the query in a arraylist in spring mvc

i 'm talking about a query like this:

```
select a,b,c,d
from table1, table2
where 
a=b ...
and not exists (
                select 
                    null 
                from 
                  ..
                where 
                   .....
               )
        union
        SELECT ....
        from
        ....
        where
        ...
```

Comment: why not, it should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233910/is-there-a-nesting-limit-for-correlated-subqueries-in-oracle

Comment: To place the query in a stored procedure, you'll have to pass a ref cursor out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400058/declaring-setting-variables-in-a-select-statement/3400602#3400602

Comment: Why not just create a view with that query?