# Oracle SQL Developer: Show REFCURSOR Results in Grid?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

As a follow-up to the question ["Get resultset from oracle stored procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170548/get-resultset-from-oracle-stored-procedure), is there a way to show the results of a stored procedure that returns a `REFCURSOR` in a grid (instead of the plain text Script Output window) within SQL Developer?

**EDIT:** The answer helped, but I'm still having a problem displaying the result set in the "View Value" window:

[image]

The columns can only be expanded a small amount, probably due to the number of results being returned. Expanding the window with the resizer control doesn't help:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can with a procedure.

**Edit:** Thanks to DCookie for simplifying my original answer.

But as a work-around you can write a function that calls the procedure and then invoke that using SQL.

e.g.

```
create or replace function callmyproc
return sys_refcursor
IS
   rc   sys_refcursor;
BEGIN

   myproc(rc);

   return rc;

END;
```

Which you can then call with:

```
   select callmyproc()
   from dual;
```

When this example is run, the SQL Developer data grid shows one result but if you scroll right and click on the edit button, you will see the results in a grid.

Comment: Or simpler yet, create a function that invokes the procedure and returns the refcursor.

Comment: @DCookie - Of course! a much more elegant way. Thanks, I've amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've accepted the answer, but for the results I'm getting back the "View Value" window shows tiny columns that I can't expand when clicking on the edit button.

Comment: @technomalogical: I see what you mean, the example is fine but a output with a lot of columns would cause problems. It appears that as the window is resized, the data grid size doesn't change. Sorry I don't know how to get round that problem!