# How to see refcursor result/output in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ref-cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way/tool to get the results from an oracle package procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526798/best-way-tool-to-get-the-results-from-an-oracle-package-procedure)
>   [Oracle SQL Developer: Show REFCURSOR Results in Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556336/oracle-sql-developer-show-refcursor-results-in-grid)

I am new to Oracle SQL Developer. I am using Oracle SQL Developer Version 3.0.
I was trying to test my SP using the following query.

```
DECLARE
  type output_cursor is ref cursor;
  P_CURSOR output_cursor;
BEGIN
  P_CURSOR := NULL;
  myPackage.mySPTest (  P_NOTIFICATION_ID => 1975357,P_CURSOR => P_CURSOR) ;
END;
```

When I ran the above query in my Oracle SQL Developer, I am getting a message 'anonymus block completed' and its not showing any result.

Can anyone help me, how to see the result.

.

Comment: what output are you expecting?  where do the 'results' of your sp go?   you probably want to write a SELECT statement against that...

Comment: Expecting a result set of row and columns.
SP results go into a .NET progam.
How do i write a select against the cursor... some sample would be nice..

Comment: Use Toad instead, it will display the contents of a refcursor for you.

Answer (score 24):

You can use a bind variable declared in SQL Developer to hold and show the results:

```
var r refcursor;
exec myPackage.mySPTest(P_NOTIFICATION_ID => 1975357, P_CURSOR => :r);
print r;
```

`exec` is shorthand for an anonymous block so this is equivalent to:

```
var r refcursor;
begin
    myPackage.mySPTest(P_NOTIFICATION_ID => 1975357, P_CURSOR => :r);
end;
/
print r;
```

Unless `P_CURSOR` is declared as something unhelpful, maybe...

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed @sathya had put two links in his comment on the question; the second (and a link in the first) point to Tony Andrews doing the same thing. I was going from an [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526798/best-way-tool-to-get-the-results-from-an-oracle-package-procedure/3527037#3527037) of my own though.

Comment: I know this is a really old answer but it's still a top result in Google... This doesn't workin SQL Developer 18 with Oracle 11g. It just throws `Ora-06550 - identifier 'R' must be declared`.

Comment: @WSC - I can't check right now but I'm at least 99% sure I've done exactly this with those versions too. You used the colon in the right place?

Comment: @WSC - nope, definitely works exactly as posted in 18.1, 18.2, 18.3 and 18.4 against an 11.2.0.4 DB. [This is from 18.4](https://pasteboard.co/IZlCiuP.png). The error really suggests you just used `r` instead of `:r` in your call.

Comment: Ah, I think you might be right. I've just tried again in SQL Developer and SQL*Plus and it does work as you said. Not entirely sure how I managed that as I could swear I copied and pasted it to make sure the format was exactly the same...

Comment: The first block with 'exec' doesn't work for Oracle 19c on SQL Developer 3.2.20.10. However, the second option with begin......end works fine. Thank you

Answer (score -3):

To view your cursor results you need to loop through your cursor and print values. You need to know column names for what your cursor is returning. You can do something like:

```
DECLARE
   type output_cursor is ref cursor;
   P_CURSOR output_cursor;
BEGIN
   P_CURSOR := NULL;
   DOCTORS_APP.get_reminders (  P_NOTIFICATION_ID => 1975357,P_CURSOR => P_CURSOR) ;
   //replace Column1 and Column2 with actual column names
   FOR CUR_VAL in P_CURSOR LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CUR_VAL.Column1||' '||CUR_VAL.Column2);
   END LOOP;
 END;
```

Comment: I tried the sample, its gives error.

Comment: what error? Have you repleced Column1 and Column2 with actual column names?

Comment: error

Error starting at line 1 in command:

Error report:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 10:
PLS-00221: 'P_CURSOR' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: The code above does not actually work.