# View refcursor as table - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When returning the output of SP in refcursor. How to view the output as a table instead of `print refcursor;` in Oracle?

Comment: if you run the package/procedure in sql developer (click on the green triangle), if you have the ref cursor as an out parameter, it will show as a table in the "output variables" tab, is that what you are asking?

Comment: U mean F9? When I click on run, then it is printing in scripts. I want to view as table (like select * from table_name output)

Comment: ok -- maybe check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556336/oracle-sql-developer-show-refcursor-results-in-grid

Answer (score 0):

Use the code editor in SQL Developer to execute the stored procedure. We'll grab the output for you - refcursors go to grids.

[image]

I talk about this in more detail [here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/12/sql-developer-tip-viewing-refcursor-output/)