# Call stored procedure in SQL Developer that returns resultset?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

I'm new to Oracle, so please bear with me. I've been searching, but I haven't found a straight answer to this.

In `SQL Developer`, I created the following stored procedure. I assume it was created because it returns message `Procedure ORACLE_GET_TOP_N_TESTS compiled`:

```
create procedure oracle_get_top_n_tests
(oracle_tests OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS 
BEGIN 
OPEN oracle_tests FOR
select * from sales.quiz_results;
END oracle_get_top_n_tests;
/
```

Now I would like to call/execute the stored procedure to view the resultset (the `select` statement) . I've tried the following, but I see no resultset:

```
variable mycursor refcursor;
exec oracle_get_top_n_tests ( :mycursor );

/* Received message PL/SQL procedure successfully completed, but no result */
```

What am I doing wrong?

I use `Database 11g Express Edition`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the result, you just aren't doing anything with it. You can [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm) it:

```
variable mycursor refcursor;
exec oracle_get_top_n_tests ( :mycursor );
print mycursor
```

The output will go in the script output window, not in a grid. (You would need to make it a function, or [use a wrapper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3560635/266304), to get the output in a grid, and even then there's an extra step to view them.)

---

Simple wrapper function:

```
create function oracle_get_top_n_tests_wrapper
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  oracle_tests SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  oracle_get_top_n_tests (oracle_tests => oracle_tests);

  return oracle_tests;
END oracle_get_top_n_tests_wrapper;
/
```

then call that as:

```
select oracle_get_top_n_tests_wrapper from dual;
```

If you run that as a script then the results will still go in the script output window; if you run it as a statement then they will go in the results grid but as a single row/column, which you can expand to see the actual contents.

---

If you aren't stuck with a procedure then you could replace that with a function instead, which then wouldn't need a wrapper:

```
-- drop function oracle_get_top_n_tests_wrapper
-- drop procedure oracle_get_top_n_tests

create function oracle_get_top_n_tests
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  oracle_tests SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN oracle_tests FOR
  select * from sales.quiz_results;

  return oracle_tests;
END oracle_get_top_n_tests;
/
```

and then call that directly:

```
select oracle_get_top_n_tests from dual;
```

with the same notes on the results that applied to the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think you can include a simple example of a function with a `select` statement?

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't referring to a function that would act as a wrapper of another object. I was referring to a function that includes a `select` statement.

Comment: In your answer you write _make it a function, or use a wrapper function_. I assume the example you posted is a wrapper function that wraps the stored procedure.

Comment: Instead of a wrapper function for a stored procedure with a `select` statement, it would be a function with a `select` statement.

Comment: I see; OK, I've added that too. The next step on from that would be a function returning a (pipelined) table, as @ValérioCosta alluded to.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the select statement in the worksheet to see the result.

If you want an object returning the resultset i would go with a function that returns a table

simple tutorial where i learned that: [Tutorial](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/PL-SQL/collection-types/return-table-from-function/index)

then you just run the statement in the worksheet `select * from table(function_oracle_get_top_n_tests);`

Comment: Thanks. Do you think you can include an example with a simple `SELECT` statement?